# How to broadcast file using Wifi from one Iphone to all connected iPhones

Tags: iphone, ipad, wifi

i am transferring file from one iPad to 2 other ipad though same application developed in Iphone OS 3.2 though Wi-Fi network.The connection breaks once file is transferred and 2 way communication is not possible.

pls help

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What mechanism are you using to transfer the file? Game Kit? Bonjour? Something else entirely?

Comment: Can you provide additional info what Robot K has asked?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Game Kit - it seems like it's the best suited thing for your application. It is made to quickly and easily create ad-hoc connections between multiple devices.